# colorama win32 calls have no effect on a win64 system

Tags: python, windows, colorama

on windows10 I have never been able to get colorama to work.
I am now on Python38 and colorama-0.4.4
I have checked that the ansitowin32 module is executing call_win32  but no color results.
Is this because my windows is based on win64?
Here is my code and output:
import colorama      # Successfully installed colorama-0.4.4

```
from colorama import Fore, Style
colorama.init(convert=True)   # to make windows calls for the escape sequences

print('default color')
print(f'{Fore.GREEN} in green {Style.RESET_ALL}.')


default color
 in green
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your line 2

It will not run without import `init`

```
from colorama import Fore, Style, init
init(convert=True)

print('default color')
print(f'{Fore.GREEN} in green {Style.RESET_ALL}.')
```

or this with `import colorama`:

```
import colorama
colorama.init(convert=True)   

print('default color')
print(f'{colorama.Fore.GREEN} in green {colorama.Style.RESET_ALL}.')
```

Comment: I made your suggested change, which is surely equivalent to my colorama.init(convert=True)

Comment: @Nick When it is true that you (import colorama), not  this(from colorama import ...).Look at my changed answer again

Comment: I appreciate your effort to resolve my problem, but both your code suggestions produce the same monchrome output.

Comment: @Nick your welcome. first is better than second example. because you just import (Fore, Style, init) but in second you import all of them, and this isn't good.  read [document](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) for Complete learning.Good luck dear friend

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the original documentation. I think my problem is expecting it to work when I am executing my .py from an IDLE shell, and not in a windows console.